# Relation between the velocity of electron and principal quantum number in Bohr's model

Tags: atomic-physics, orbitals

I know the mathematical derivation of:

$v = (2.19)10^{-6} \dfrac Zn \text{m/s} $

> $ \implies v\propto \dfrac1n$

What is the intuition behind this (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

The farther the electron from the nucleus is, the slower the electron velocity becomes in a bound state.